# How can i grab the domain name from the firefox's places.sqlite file with python script

Tags: python, url, firefox, browser-history

How can anyone grab the list of URLs from the Firefox's places.sqlite file?
Can anyone help me out with any python script.

Comment: If you are working with SQLite databases, you should use the [`sqlite3` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect("<path_to>/places.sqlite")
urls = db.execute("select url from moz_places").fetchall()
```

Comment: showing error msg "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: moz_places"